# Error in Filebeat logs - not able to view data in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

Recently upgraded to 7.17.7 filebeat. Using elasticsearch, kibana and filebeat, all 7.17.7. However , I am not able to see the logs in kibana, as filebeat is not sending the logs to elasticsearch and kibana. In filebeat saw error -

```
ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: resource 'filebeat-7.17.7' exists, but it is not an alias
```

Can someone help to figure out what could be the cause and solution for this error?

restarted filebeat, but didnt help.

Filebeat config -

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/www/vhosts/rshop/current/var/log/*.log
  multiline.pattern: ^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.kibana:
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  indices:
    - index: "r-logs-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.regexp:
        log.file.path: '^.+\/var\/log\/recalculation\.log$'
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: "filebeat-6.8.7-monolog-pipeline"
      when.or:
        - regexp:
            log.file.path: '^.+\/var\/log\/recalculation\.log$' 
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0755
```

Comment: Please share your filebeat config file in the question.

Comment: Added in question.

Answer (score 1):

@NKumar most likely its an upgrade issue from legacy to new index templates, which will happen if you don't mark them as true for overwriting.

Can you please provide info from what version of stack did you upgrade to 7.17?

Also, the quick solution would be to just add an alias to your filebeat index as:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions" : [
{
  "add" : {
    "index" : "filebeat-7.17.7",
    "alias" : "filebeat-7.17.7_1",
    "is_write_index" : true
  }
}
]}
```

or a more persistent solution would be to add following setting in filebeat:

```
setup.template.settings:
  setup.template.enabled: true
  setup.template.overwrite: true
```

Answer (score 0):

it is due to filebeat version 7.17, revert it back to older version it should be able to connect. please check limitations of filebeat 7.17.  Please note that, Beats versions newer than 7.12.x are not supported by OpenSearch. If you must update the Beats agent(s) in your environment to a newer version, you can work around the incompatibility by directing traffic from Beats to Logstash and using the Logstash Output plugin to ingest the data to OpenSearch.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/tools/index/#downloads